# Hide specific row of a table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have this simple table:

[image]

```
<v-simple-table>
    <template v-slot:default class="my-20 py-20">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left">Attribute</th>
                <th class="text-left">Operator</th>
                <th class="text-left">Values</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(ruleDetail, j) in ruleDetails">
                <td>{{ ruleDetail.attribute_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ ruleDetail.operator_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ ruleDetail.value }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </template>
</v-simple-table>
```

I would like to hide the row where

`ruleDetail.attribute_name == Label batch`

What is the best practice to do that?

---

```
//all from API 
//this.ruleDetails = response.data.details 

//tried to filter, but it's not working.

    this.ruleDetails = response.data.campaigns.filter((item) => {
        return item.attribute_name != 'Label batch'
    })
```

Comment: You'd need a `computed` property for that

Comment: Is it the best practice ? I was thinking to do a `v-if` inside the `v-for`, but I am not sure if's allowed in vue.js. I came from a Laravel PHP background, and we can do something like that in a blade file.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use includes in filter in computed property :

```
computed: {
  filteredRules() {
    return this.ruleDetails.filter((item) => !item.attribute_name.toLowerCase().includes(('Label batch').toLowerCase())
  }
}
```

and then in templae:

```
<tr v-for="(ruleDetail, j) in filteredRules">
```

Comment: so you suggest, that we polish the data before the looping, not during the looping. right ?

Comment: Your return statement seems to cause this error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')`

Comment: @code-8 hey mate, try now with computed property, I corrected my answer

Comment: What’s compute ? Why is it so important ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect and it should work. One suggestion, cross check `response.data.campaigns` to see if you are getting the proper response in this or not.

Working Demo as per the code you posted **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      campaigns: [
        {
          attribute_name: 'UV Index (Current Weather)',
          operator_name: 'Lesser number',
          value: 7
        },
        {
          attribute_name: 'Temperature (Current Weather)',
          operator_name: 'Greater or equal number',
          value: 17
        },
        {
          attribute_name: 'Label batch',
          operator_name: 'Equal numbers',
          value: 66235
        }
      ],
      ruleDetails: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.ruleDetails = this.campaigns.filter((item) => {
        return item.attribute_name != 'Label batch'
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-simple-table>
      <template v-slot:default>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left">Attribute</th>
                <th class="text-left">Operator</th>
                <th class="text-left">Values</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(ruleDetail, j) in ruleDetails">
                <td>{{ ruleDetail.attribute_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ ruleDetail.operator_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ ruleDetail.value }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </template>
    </v-simple-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```